# JPA how to sync unmanaged entity object with database (call by value)

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

Following Problem:

Relation:  |Shop| --1--------n--> |Products|

So I have an Entity named shop that can have many products.

I developed a function called **void addProductToShop(Shop shop, Product product);**

It looks something like this:

```
public void addProductToShop(Shop shop, Product product)
{
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    shop = entityManager.merge(shop);
    shop.getProductList.add(product);

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
```

Everything works fine and is written correctly to the database.
The Problem is, that the two Entities are not updated in my Application code.

So after calling **addProductToShop(shop, product);** you have to update the two variables **shop** and **product** because they don't have the latest changes (because of callByValue).

But as consumer of this function I assume that my parameters are changed after the call and not only the database.
How can I achieve this without requesting an update of **shop** and **product** after each function call.

Are there any best practices?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I think entityManager.refresh(Object) is what you need to call for both shop and product.

Comment: How should I use refresh in my code?
I can not call refresh on the two parameters because they are not managed.

I also do not get why **persist()** updates the object and **merge()** doesn't.

Could someone suggest a solution where I input theses parameters do the changes on the database and have them updated for the caller of this function?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

My mistake was that I should first change the entities from the parameters and **then** do a merge...

So the parameters have the same state as the merged entities have.

Little error in reasoning...

Regards,
Alex